# How to fix error after enable proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

After I enable proguard to build release my programe have error:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [.../build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [.../build/intermediates/classes/release(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v7/recyclerview/R$dimen.class]))
```

Before my program work fine. I only update version of library on build.gradle file.

I checked some question on stackoverflow and update

```
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.3'
    targetSdkVersion = 23
    minSdkVersion = 16
```

And update support library to 23.4.0, play-service to 9.0.1

Here is check independence:

```
  ------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

_debugAndroidTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1
     \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1

_debugAndroidTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1
     \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1

_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
+--- project :app:libraries:FloatingTabWidget
|    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
+--- project :FFmpegAndroid
+--- project :app:libraries:android-map-utils
|    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.1
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.1
|         |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
+--- project :app:libraries:aFileChooser
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.7
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-core:0.2.6
|    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-theme-material:0.2.6
|    |    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    |    \--- com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-core:0.2.6 (*)
|    \--- com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2
|         \--- com.google.android:android:2.2.1
|              +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|              +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|              |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|              |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|              |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
|              +--- org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1
|              +--- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2
|              +--- xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c
|              \--- org.json:json:20080701
+--- com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.4.8
|    +--- com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.7 (*)
|    +--- com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-theme-material:0.2.6 (*)
|    +--- com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:design:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.11
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.picasso:picasso:2.5.2.4b
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0 -> 2.6.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0 -> 2.6.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.intellij:annotations:12.0
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.exif:android-exif-extended:1.0.6
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2 -> 3.4
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache:disklrumulticache:1.0.6
|    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    |    \--- com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.viewrevealanimator:view-reveal-animator:1.1.4
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3
|    |    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13 -> 1.1.0
|    +--- it.sephiroth:rxbroadcast:0.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.1.0
|    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:0.3.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.3.0
|    |    |    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0 -> 23.4.0
|    |    |    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.1.0
|    |    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.1.0
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.1.0
|    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2 (*)
|    +--- com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 23.4.0
|    +--- com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.common:common-ui:1.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 -> 9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.4
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.ab:ab-test:2.0.5
|    +--- de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0 (*)
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.6.0 (*)
|    \--- com.infstory:proguard-annotations:1.0.2
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
+--- com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1
+--- net.nend.android:nend-adapter:1.2.4
|    \--- net.nend.android:nend-sdk:+ -> 3.1.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0 -> 9.0.1
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.0.1
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1 -> 3.2.0 (*)
+--- com.github.waynell:VideoListPlayer:1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0-RC1
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1 -> 3.2.0 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1 (*)

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
+--- project :app:libraries:FloatingTabWidget
|    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
+--- project :FFmpegAndroid
+--- project :app:libraries:android-map-utils
|    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.1
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.1
|         |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
+--- project :app:libraries:aFileChooser
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1 (*)
+--- com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.7
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-core:0.2.6
|    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-theme-material:0.2.6
|    |    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    |    \--- com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-core:0.2.6 (*)
|    \--- com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2
|         \--- com.google.android:android:2.2.1
|              +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|              +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|              |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|              |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|              |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
|              +--- org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1
|              +--- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2
|              +--- xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c
|              \--- org.json:json:20080701
+--- com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.4.8
|    +--- com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.7 (*)
|    +--- com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-theme-material:0.2.6 (*)
|    +--- com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:design:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.11
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.picasso:picasso:2.5.2.4b
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0 -> 2.6.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0 -> 2.6.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.intellij:annotations:12.0
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.exif:android-exif-extended:1.0.6
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2 -> 3.4
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache:disklrumulticache:1.0.6
|    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    |    \--- com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.viewrevealanimator:view-reveal-animator:1.1.4
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3
|    |    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13 -> 1.1.0
|    +--- it.sephiroth:rxbroadcast:0.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.1.0
|    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:0.3.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.3.0
|    |    |    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0 -> 23.4.0
|    |    |    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.1.0
|    |    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.1.0
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.1.0
|    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2 (*)
|    +--- com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 23.4.0
|    +--- com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.common:common-ui:1.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 -> 9.0.1 (*)
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.4
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.ab:ab-test:2.0.5
|    +--- de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0 (*)
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.6.0 (*)
|    \--- com.infstory:proguard-annotations:1.0.2
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
+--- com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1
+--- net.nend.android:nend-adapter:1.2.4
|    \--- net.nend.android:nend-sdk:+ -> 3.1.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0 -> 9.0.1
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.0.1
|         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.1 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1 -> 3.2.0 (*)
+--- com.github.waynell:VideoListPlayer:1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1 -> 23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0-RC1
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1 -> 3.2.0 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1 (*)
```

Dependencies:

```
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: 'android-support-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0') {
        force = true
        exclude (group: 'com.squareup.okio', module:'okio')
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-vector-drawable'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:design:23.4.0'){
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.6.0'){
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
//        exclude module: 'play-services-basement'
//        exclude module: 'play-services-tasks'
    }
    compile ('com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.7'){
//        exclude module: 'alertdialogpro-core'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'

    }
    compile ('com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.4.8'){
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'commons-lang3'
        exclude module: 'rxjava'
//        exclude module: 'rxlifecycle'
//        exclude module: 'rxbinding'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'android-priority-jobqueue'
        exclude module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude module: 'auth'
        exclude module: 'alertdialogpro-theme-material'
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
        exclude module: 'okhttp-urlconnection'

    }
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1'
    compile ('net.nend.android:nend-adapter:1.2.4'){
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'play-services-basement'
        exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
    }
    compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0') {
        exclude group: 'glide-parent'
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile ('com.github.waynell:VideoListPlayer:1.1'){
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0'){
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude module: 'play-services-basement'
    }
    compile (project(':app:libraries:FloatingTabWidget')){
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    compile project(':FFmpegAndroid')
    compile (project(':app:libraries:android-map-utils')){
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    compile (project(':app:libraries:aFileChooser')){
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
```

Comment: Oh, wow, that's a lot of dependencies. But, yeah, looks like a lot of those overlap somewhat, so you're going to need to setup Gradle exclude commands

Comment: yes, there are many dependencies. I don't know where I should begin

Comment: Well, it's a common anti-pattern to include a lot of libraries, so find out which ones you don't need

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 Do I need to exclude sublibrary within a library ?

Comment: Not sure, really, but `com.adobe.creativesdk` seems to be the biggest one

Comment: Yes, it reuse a lot of library and I'm not sure what is the library need exclude. Eeverything seems very craft.

Comment: The error specifically calls out `recyclerview`, so see which libraries use that

Comment: It looks like the recyclerview library is included as a transitive dependency from various modules: FloatingTabWidget, android-map-utils. Did you enable transitive = true for them?

Comment: Can you post you proguard config file?

Comment: Hi @ChrisAndrew, I see that when I remove     compile 'net.nend.android:nend-adapter:1.2.4' everything work fine. Because I added excude for recyclerview with this library. I don't know reason of this error.